# In reactive java how to collect all elements from flux, only if element value the same as first

Tags: java, reactor

I have a `Flux<Integer>`

now I want to collect all elements from this flux where currentElement <= firstElement

Given I have a `Flux.from(5, 6, 4, 7, 3)`, I want to have `5,4,3` in the resulting set

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can do, pick the first element from flux.

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(5, 9, 8, 4, 3, 6);
Integer firstElement = flux.blockFirst();
```

Then use that element to prepare the filter predicate.

```
List<Integer> numbers = flux.toStream()
               .filter(num -> num <= firstElement)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Cool, but is it possible to combine it in a single chain?

Comment: @a3dsfcv not aware of any.

Answer (score 2):

See `Flux.switchOnFirst()`:

```
 * Transform the current {@link Flux<T>} once it emits its first element, making a
 * conditional transformation possible. This operator first requests one element
 * from the source then applies a transformation derived from the first {@link Signal}
 * and the source. The whole source (including the first signal) is passed as second
 * argument to the {@link BiFunction} and it is very strongly advised to always build
 * upon with operators (see below).
```

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#switchOnFirst-java.util.function.BiFunction-